# Internet Explorer 7 Google Map Rendering Problem

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer-7

Hi I'm having some trouble with IE7 when doing a map.
I've made an xml and ajaxed it to grab points based on where the user is on the map.
It works well, and in FF, IE8 no problems when they click the points. On IE7 it firstly misses the cross at the top right, has some problems with the border (fixed that with some margin) and more importantly cuts out an portion of the image which I can't figure out.

[image]

I've attatched an image and what you see there is basically an a tag with a background image.
I've taken the title out as I thought that might cause it. Basically I'm stumpped any ideas.
Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in Internet Explorer which has to do with how transparent PNGs are scaled when using the Zooming feature of the browser.  It's difficult to reproduce because it's a local browser setting.

It happens even in maps.google.com. See the example below at 125% zoom, using Internet Explorer 8:

[image]

Is your zoom set to anything other than 100%?

Comment: Sorry jigged around with it and it happens no matter what the zoom was on 100%,75% 125%

Comment: Good Idea, though what I think might help is a way to force the map to do a redraw - is this possible?

Comment: @Richard: Do you mean that a `map.setCenter()` fixes the rendering problem?

Comment: No I just wanted to know is that possible in the end I just wrote some code to remove the shadow as that was causing the problems in IE 7. Bit of a hack but hopefully IE7 will die shortly!